# Check for functionality of Subaru EyeSight package

Tags: subaru, safety, active-lane-assist

I'm purchasing a used Subaru Crosstrek this week. It's a 2017 Sport model with the "Technology Package" meaning it has rear/side vehicle detection (standard on Sport model) plus Subaru's EyeSight package (part of the Technology Package).

Is there any **safe** way to test the rear/side vehicle detection or or the EyeSight package to make sure they're functional? I can see that there are buttons to turn them on and off, but if they're on, how do you know they're really doing their thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The dealer has tools to calibrate the eyesight package (essential if the windscreen ever has to be replaced, for example). They should be able to run a comprehensive test. Yes, it will cost money, but replacing those systems if they're broken would make the vehicle an unrealistic purchase. You can also ask them to do a complete pre-purchase inspection, in case something else is not working correctly (no, not thinking about that CVT transmission at all... which stopped us from buying any more Subaru cars ever again...)

Comment: Is that the CVT that fails when tires of differing sizes are used?

Comment: @SolarMike - No, that's the center viscous diff; they've had that problem even before the CVT. Their CVT can't tow anything (well, 1,500lbs. Even a utility trailer is 600lbs, so you can't get much on there). No; I had an extended test drive in a brand new one (for three months), and it used to lose power randomly when pulling out of junctions. Frightening.

Comment: Hope you are happy with your car now. Mate had a subaru and it was fine - 6 cyl version went well.